# How to check if CGVector is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I'm curious how I would use an if statement to see if a `CGVector` variable is nil, as objects are done like so:

```
if (!object){

    //Do This

}
```

But with `CGVector` it's not an object (As I know of). How would I determine if my `CGVector` variable is nil?

Comment: `CGVector` is a `struct`. See there:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414809/default-value-of-an-objective-c-struct-and-how-to-test (for pointer explanation).
Maybe you need to check: `if(yourVector.dx == 0 && yourVector.dy == 0)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know it is a struct not an object

```
struct CGVector {
   CGFloat dx;
   CGFloat dy;
};
typedef struct CGVector CGVector;
```

Edit:

There is no such thing to check if a struct is `nil`.

Even if you check with `dx==0` and `dy==0`, this is not correct at all an `{0,0}` is still a valid vector point.

For similar approach/question : [How do I check if a CGPoint has been initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928893/how-do-i-check-if-a-cgpoint-has-been-initialised)